# How do I print stars and a sequence of numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to print:

```
* * * *
* * * 1
* * 1 2
* 1 2 3
```

I have tried these codes:

```
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1)
   print(str("* "*(n-i)) + str(x for x in range(1, n+1)))
```

but the output says generator.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include the `print` statement, as `str` only returns the value, on its own it will not write to the console (the interactive interpreter will automatically `print(repr(_))` as a matter of convenience, but not in an actual program). You may wish to do `print(str(...))`.

Comment: thank you, I did use print() but the output says ``` <generator>```

Comment: `str(x for x in range(1, n+1)` -- This is why you are getting that generator expression;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 3
for i in range(0, n+1):
    print(str("* "*(n-i+1)) + ' '.join([str(x) for x in range(1, i+1)]))
```

Output:

```
* * * * 
* * * 1
* * 1 2
* 1 2 3
```

The way to generate such a concatenation of string is to make a list of strings using list comprehension and then use `join` function to join all the element of the list